# What's the name of the psychiatric condition where small tasks appear daunting?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

What's the name of the psychiatric condition where small tasks appear daunting, assuming such a name even exists in English?

Searches through google just bring up results like anxiety and depression, but those aren't remotely similar to what I'm looking for because those are big conditions that relate to many aspects of a person. Ideally the word would be specific to the person's perspective regarding effort.

In a sentence it would be something simple like,

> "Her ______ keeps her from going to the store. Shopping is too much for her
>   to do."

Comment: I've combed the DSM-5's list of disorders and I don't know that there is a better descriptor than Generalized Anxiety Disorder for this kind of situation. I am also, however, not a psychologist. :)

Comment: "Sense of overwhelment", "stress and overwhelment" ?

Comment: This is probably better asked in a specialist site, something about clinical psychology. Also, your question is very general, lots of conditions could be the cause of such problems. Fear of going to the store is a sign of agoraphobia or social anxiety. Trouble doing small tasks is a sign of depression. Psychiatric disorders, severe or mild, can express themselves in a lot of ways.

Comment: This is a fairly common problem, so there must be a term somewhere for it.  Of course, it's closely linked to depression.

Answer (score 1):

*condition where small tasks appear daunting* reminded me of the phrase [making a mountain out of  a molehill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill), and the article for that describes it as a form of **cognitive distortion**, specifically [exaggeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaggeration).

Unfortunately, exaggeration as a word isn't strongly connected to psychiatry terms, it's more likely to evoke simple boasting. A [psychiatry book](https://books.google.com/books?id=AANMupaUs6UC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=making%20mountains%20molehills#v=onepage&q=making%20mountains%20molehills&f=false) classifies this as **paranoid personality disorder**, which is a broad term covering other afflictions as well.

Perhaps you can use ***cognitive exaggeration paranoia*** to be a suitable term for your example, as in

> "Her cognitive exaggeration paranoia keeps her from going to the
>   store. Shopping is too much for her to do."

This still looks awkward to me, but I can't think of a better fit as a phrase. Might be simpler to use *tendency to make mountains out of molehills* instead, if that is a close enough equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

a **delusion**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/delusion)  Both of the following are Psychiatric related:

> 1. a mistaken or misleading opinion, idea, belief.
> 2. a belief held in the face of evidence to the contrary, that is resistant to all reason.

As in:

"Her *delusions* keeps her from going to the store. Shopping is too much for her to do."

Answer (score 0):

Medical term:  if you are looking for a medical designation this is really not the best forum to match a term with symptoms/traits

If you are looking for a **non-clinical English word** that could **~suggest~** an **unusual reaction** to things in ways that would not effect others you might consider **nervous** (although if nervous were used to not describe a person's nature but their specific state at a given time it means something a bit different as we know)

In my opinion, "nervous' is a relative term to "normal" -as the definition below points out 'easily' or 'sensitive' point that direction.

> [**Nervous** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nervous)
>
> 1 Easily agitated or alarmed.
>
> *‘a sensitive, nervous person’*
>
> 1.1 Anxious or apprehensive.
>
> *‘staying in the house on her own made her nervous’*
>
> *‘he's nervous of speaking in public’*
>
> 1.2 (of a feeling or reaction) resulting from anxiety or anticipation.
>
> ‘nervous energy’
>
> 2 Relating to or affecting the nerves.
>
> *‘a nervous disorder’*

You might use words like "nature" or words of magnitude to suggest more.

"Their **nervous nature** never let them display their aptitude to it's justice."

"Their **extreme nervousness** made the loud sounds on the avenue make the walk to the store more than they could bear."

also **nerves** could be another approach.

"Their **nerves** impeded their test performance"